# Checking oil on a newly-aquired used motorbike

Tags: motorcycle, oil, maintenance, oil-change

I've recently bought a used motorbike and am unsure of how to gauge the age/condition of its oil: Neither did I fill the oil in the first place (so I don't know what colour it used to be) nor have I got much experience in what motorcycle oil "usually" looks like:

[image: Dipstick]

As you can see in the photo above, the dipstick is wet up to the first "ridge", and it is a dark albeit transparent caramel (but not black or opaque brown). Does the oil look to be in "maintained" condition?-- Should I simply wait until the next scheduled check-up to replace it (which is in about 500km anyway)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would just do the maintenance 500km early. it doesn't have to be all that precisely on the intervals. it's s good way to get more familiar with the new bike.

I always do a full oil change I'm taking possession of s new bike, since there is no economic way to know when it was last changed, or with what. getting the oil tested can be done, but it costs as much as an oil change anyway.